# Create a file in the installer location - Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a application to create a text file in the location, where the installer is in. When the application is installed it has to create a file in the location where actually the installer is placed. how to do in Java.

Comment: Why can't the installer do this?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis, I'm creating a installer, it has to create a file in the installer directory actually where the exe file is located. how to find it at the runtime of the java.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis, I can find the location of installation directory (e.g: C:\) but I need to find the location of where the installer is. (i.e) the installer may in USB or any other drives such as D:,E: . I want to create file over there.

Answer (score 0):

In any Java application, you can identify the current working directory by doing something like this:

```
File workingDir = new File("someFileName").getParentFile().toAbsoluteFile();
```

Alternate solution:

```
File workingDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

See: [Definition of standard System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--)

Use either of the above solutions, and create your file object with this code:

```
File textFile = new File(workingDir, "<your file name here>");
```

Comment: Its working in the IDE, but I don't know where it is when make it as a installer. When I installed it, no idea where it is created.

Comment: I can find the location of installation directory (e.g: C:\) but I need to find the location of where the installer is. (i.e) the installer may in USB or any other drives such as D:,E: . I want to create file over there.